# How to send push notifications using aws in china region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification

Can we create an application in AWS SNS in china region like we do in US region for android, iOS or baidu ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.
AWS SNS is one of the [available services in China](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/about-aws/china/faqs/#icp-needed-cn).

For more details click [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sns-mobile-push-update-baidu-windows/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/06/12/sns-now-has-windows-support-and-china-android-support-with-baidu/)

Comment: We dont have feature in AWS China - cn-north-1 (beijing region) to create an application in SNS with particular provider like GCM, APNS or Baidu. Instead we have to contact SNS in us-east from china to do that as **confirmed from AWS support**.
However, aws document for china shows support for push notifications. Confusing.

Comment: Oops. That's indeed confusing. Did you tell the AWS support guy about the document discrepancy